# is there a faster way to work with nested linq query?

Tags: linq, linqpad

I am trying to query a table with nested linq query. My query working but is too slow. I have almost 400k row. And this query work 10 seconds for 1000 rows. For 400k I think its about to 2 hours.

I have rows like this

```
StudentNumber - DepartmentID
n100 - 1
n100 - 1
n105 - 1    
n105 - 2
n107 - 1
```

I want the students which have different department ID. My results looks like this.

```
StudentID - List
n105 - 1 2
```

And my query provides it. But slowly.

```
var sorgu = (from yok in YOKAktarim
    group yok by yok.StudentID into g
    select new {
        g.Key,
        liste=(from birim in YOKAktarim where birim.StudentID == g.Key select new { birim.DepartmentID }).ToList().GroupBy (x => x.DepartmentID).Count()>1 ? (from birim in YOKAktarim where birim.StudentID == g.Key select new { birim.DepartmentID }).GroupBy(x => x.DepartmentID).Select(x => x.Key).ToList() : null,
    }).Take(1000).ToList();


Console.WriteLine(sorgu.Where (s => s.liste != null).OrderBy (s => s.Key));
```

I wrote this query with linqpad C# statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For 400K records you should be able to return the student ids and department ids into an in-memory list.

```
 var list1 = (from r in YOKAktarim  
            group r by new { r.StudentID, r.DepartmentID} into g  
            select g.Key
           ).ToList();
```

Once you have this list, you should be able to group by StudentID and select those students who have more than one record.

```
  var list2 = (from r in list1 group r by r.StudentID into g 
               where g.Count() > 1 
               select new 
                  { 
                      StudentID = g.Key, 
                      Departments = g.Select(a => a.DepartmentID).ToList()
                  }  
               ).ToList();
```

This should be faster as it only hits the sql database once, rather than hundreds of thousands of times.

Answer (score 1):

You're iterating your source collection (`YOKAktarim`) three times, which makes your query *O(n^3)` query. It's going to be slow.

Instead of going back to source collection to get content of the group you can simply iterate over `g`.

```
var sorgu = (from yok in YOKAktarim
    group yok by yok.StudentID into g
    select new {
        g.Key,
        liste = from birim in g select new { birim.DepartmentID }).ToList().GroupBy (x => x.DepartmentID).Count()>1 ? (from birim in g select new { birim.DepartmentID }).GroupBy(x => x.DepartmentID).Select(x => x.Key).ToList() : null,
    }).Take(1000).ToList();
```

However, that's still not optimal, because you're doing a lot of redundant subgrouping. Your query is pretty much equivalent to:

```
from yok in YOKAktarim
group yok by yok.StudentID into g
let departments = g.Select(g => g.DepartmentID).Distinct().ToList()
where departments.Count() > 1
select new {
    g.Key,
    liste = departments
}).Take(1000).ToList();
```

Comment: I'm not saying you did :) @İsmailHakkıŞen Let me know if it's faster now.

Comment: Let me first make clear I'm not the downvoter. I agree with your query transformation, just to note that the `where` clause you added makes it non equivalent to the original which projects `null`. Which was unclear logic anyway :-)

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek I tried your query but "g.Select" not return departmentID. But you give me different vision. I'm trying something new.

Answer (score -2):

I can't speak for the correctness of that monster, but simply removing all `ToList()` calls except the outermost one will fix your issue.

Comment: That's not the issue. Query is highly not optimal even without `ToList` calls.